# Toilet overflowed

Tags: toilet

Came home to water on the inside of (closed ) toilet lids and some water on floor around them on both upstairs and basement toilets when no one was home.  We have a toilet on second floor that was completely dry.  Any thoughts ?

Comment: It looked as if there were a burst of water for a few seconds

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Do you know if your vent stacks are clear? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Is the toileton the second floor used regularly? Were any tubs or wash basins dirty with residue that wasn't there before? were they backed up? how quickly does a sink drain when you pull a plug on it?

Comment: Do you have a septic system or use town sewer? Is the stack vent clear?

Comment: Check with your neighbors and municipality as to whether there was a large-scale drain issue.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like there was backflow in your sewer system. Could have been caused by a lot of things.

Last year our city sent out a notice that they were going to be power washing the sewer lines on a certain day, and suggested keep toilet lids down and perhaps to put a towel over the bowl to keep any splashing contained. You could maybe give your city a call and ask if they were doing anything similar?

If it happens again, maybe ask around the neighborhood if anyone else had it too.

Comment: Yikes; backflowed so bad that it filled the upstairs toilet enough to siphon itself dry, +1. To prevent this in the future you need a backflow preventer on the main sewer line.